# Texmaker: "Log File not found !" (Note: I have also installed TeX Live 2019)

Tags: texmaker, texlive-2019

I'm having a problem with my Texmaker because every time I compile the texfile the "Log File not found !" message keeps appearing. [image] I have also installed Tex Live 2019, but I installed it in D:/. So I decided to configure my Texmaker so that it can access both latex.exe and pdflatex.exe. [image] But the problem is still not solved. Also when I had installed the Tex Live 2019, I observed that my antivirus blocked some of its components. [image]. I had thought that maybe this could be the problem, so I unblocked all of them. But the problem is still not solved. Can anyone help me on this matter?

**EDITTED:**
After running `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex`, this is what it shows[image]

Comment: You have entries for texlive and for miktex in your settings. That can't be right. Open a command line and type `where pdflatex` to find out which tex system is actually first in your path.

Comment: It gives D:\Programs\texlive\2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe

Comment: The only configurations I changed in the Texmaker are LaTeX and PdfLaTex (and the Embed option).

Comment: Go in the command line to the folder of your file and try to compile it with `pdflatex trial`. If is works replace the pdflatex entry with `pdflatex %` and try again in texmaker. If this doesn't work: ask the maintainer of texmaker for support, these log-file error seems to happen quite often with this editor.

Comment: I shows "I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!"

Comment: run `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex`. Does this create a format?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by whether it created a format or not, but I showed the result above.

Comment: your texlive installation looks quite broken. `fmtutil-user` doesn't find any `fmtutil.cnf`, and `fmtutil-sys` can't write a format due to some permission problem. I can't tell you what went wrong. You could ask on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: The same problem occurs with recently installed miktex and texmaker (which alsso creates dvi files when invoking pdflatex ! ) The problem was solved bu using the user defined quick compile as `pdftex -output-format=pdf -interaction=nonstopmode "&latex" %` . So the problem likely comes from this recent version of TeXmaker.

Comment: @Jhor I doubt that this is the "same" problem, the OP has problems to create the formats even if texmaker isn't used at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes not really the same but quite similar in the "log file not found" and bogous compilation encoutered by TeXmaker, beside several permission problems too